# Longest common sub-sequence with a certain property?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

We say that a sequence of numbers **x(1)**,**x(2)**,...,**x(k)** is **zigzag** if no three of its consecutive elements create a **nonincreasing** or **nondecreasing** sequence. More precisely, for all i=1,2,...,k-2 either

```
x(i) >( x(i+1),x(i-1) )  

or

x(i) < ( x(i+1) , x(i-1))
```

I have two sequences of numbers **a(1),a(2),...,a(n)** and **b(1),b(2),...,b(m)**. The problem is to compute the **length of their longest common zigzag subsequence**. In other words, you're going to delete elements from the two sequences so that they are equal, and so that they're a zigzag sequence. If the minimum number of elements required to do this is k then your answer is m+n-2k.

**Note.  sequences with length two and one are trivially zigzag**

Now i tried writing a memoized recursive solution for the same using the below state variables

```
i= current position of sequence 1.
j= current position of sequence 2.
last= last taken number in the zigzag sequence currently being considered.
direction = current requirement of the number i.e. should it be greater than previous,less or same;
```

i call the below function with

```
magic(0,0,Integer.MIN_VALUE,0);
```

Here Integer.MIN_VALUE  is used a sentinel value denoting no numbers are taken yet in the sequence.
The function is given below:

```
static int magic(int i, int j, int last, int direction) {

  if (hm.containsKey(i + " " + j + " " + last + " " + direction))
   return hm.get(i + " " + j + " " + last + " " + direction);


  if (i == seq1.length || j == seq2.length) {
   return 0;

  }



  int take_both = 0, leave_both = 0, leave1 = 0, leave2 = 0;
  if (seq1[i] == seq2[j] && last == Integer.MIN_VALUE)
   take_both = 1 + magic(i + 1, j + 1, seq1[i], direction); // this is the first digit  hence direction is 0.
  else if (seq1[i] == seq2[j] && (direction == 0 || direction == 1 && seq1[i] > last || direction == -1 && seq1[i] < last))
   take_both = 1 + magic(i + 1, j + 1, seq1[i], last != seq1[i] ? (last > seq1[i] ? 1 : -1) : 2);


  leave_both = magic(i + 1, j + 1, last, direction);

  leave1 = magic(i + 1, j, last, direction);
  leave2 = magic(i, j + 1, last, direction);
  int ans;

  ans = Math.max(Math.max(Math.max(take_both, leave_both), leave1), leave2);
  hm.put(i + " " + j + " " + last + " " + direction, ans);
  return ans;

 }
```

Now the above code is working for as much test cases i could make, but the complexity is high.
How do i reduce the time complexity,can i eliminate some state variables here? is there a efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of the common sequence? Do you mean common by where they occur or by the values? 1,2,1,2,1,2,1 / 3,2,3,2,3,2... what's the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's reduce the number of states: Let `f(i, j, d)` be the length of the longest common zig-zag sequence starting at position i in the first string and position j in the second string and starting with direction d (up or down).

We have the recurrence

```
f(i, j, up) >= MAX(i' > i, j' > j : f(i', j', up))
if s1[i] = s2[j]:
    f(i, j, up) >= MAX(i' > i, j' > j, s1[i'] > x : f(i', j', down))
```

an similar for the `down` direction. Solving this in a straightforward way
will lead to a runtime of something like O(n<sup>4</sup> · W) where W is the range of integers in the array. W is not polynomially bounded, so we definitely want to get rid of this factor, and ideally a couple of n factors along the way.

To solve the first part, you have to find the maximum f(i', j', up) with
i' > i and j' > j. This is a standard standard 2-d orthogonal range maximum query.

For the second case, you need to find the maximum (i', j', down) with i' > i, j' > j and s1[i'] > s1[i]. That is a range maximum query in the rectangle (i, ∞) x (j, ∞) x (s1[i], ∞).

Now having 3 dimensions here looks scary. However, if we process the states in say, decreasing order of i, then we can get rid of one dimension.
We thus reduced the problem to a range query in the rectangle (j, ∞) x (s1[i], ∞). Coordinate compression gets the dimension of values down to O(n).

You can use a 2-d data structure such as a [range tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree) or binary-indexed tree to solve both kinds of range queries in O(log<sup>2</sup> n). The total runtime will be O(n<sup>2</sup> · log<sup>2</sup> n).

You can get rid of one log factor using fractional cascading, but that is associated with a high constant factor. The runtime is then only one log-factor short of that for finding the longest common subsequence, which seems like a lower-bound for our problem.

Comment: Exuse my ignorance but can you explain the recurrence ,more elaboratately ? How did you reduce it to three variables ?

Comment: @Sam The important realization is that if you force the elements i and j to actually be part of the sequences, you know the last value from them, and you don't need to represent it explicitly in the state